# What happens if I connect more than 50 devices to Windows Server Essentials?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

I work on a network with currently about 45 PCs connected to Windows Server Essential 2012. This edition has a limitation of maximum 50 devices.
Now I want to replace 10 of the PCs. If possible I like to prepare first the 10 new PCs and connect them to the server. And after everything works I want to remove the old PCs. So temporary (maybe for a day or two) I would have 55 PCs connected to a server which is limited to 50 devices.
Does anybody know what happens if I connect more than 50 devices? Will I get maybe a warning but it will work for a few days or what will happen?
Edit: With "connect" I mean: join the domain

Comment: Interesting question. I want to know too. I bet there will be an "Access denied" error of some sort but I don't know about the full repercussions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Server Essentials. What do you mean by connect? Do you mean join a domain, get a DHCP lease, connect to a network share, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I remember for another server product I just saw log entries like "you exceed you licenses" or something similar, but it still worked.  For clarification: This is about PCs joining the domain.  Thanks for "Server Fault". I have to admit I was not aware that exist ;)

Comment: Thanks for migrating this question to ServerFault. I asked a very similar question on ServerFault about and hour ago. Now I deleted that questions to avoid duplicates.