# Where can I check in Windows Server Essential how many devices are connected?

Tags: windows, windows-server-essentials

I use Windows Server Essentials which allows up to 50 devices.
Where can I check how many devices are connected (without running around in the offices and counting)?

If I look in the list of computers in the AD I will see also older PCs which are maybe not connected anymore.

I asked a related question some time ago but never received an answer:
[What happens if I connect more than 50 devices to Windows Server Essentials?](https://serverfault.com/questions/831957/what-happens-if-i-connect-more-than-50-devices-to-windows-server-essentials)

Comment: I'm assuming you're in a pretty small environment because you're running essentials. You could probably try running something like Angry IP scanner to see how many hosts are connected to the same subnet as the server and their respective hostnames. This will only show you the hosts that are currently running however so you might miss some machines that are turned off.

Comment: Bel Arc advisor could also be a good tool for this